Как отправить сообщение всем участникам группогого чата?
Искал везде но не получается создать код созыва всех пользователей в конкретном чате группы.
from aiogram import Bot, types, Dispatcher, executor
from datetime import datetime
import asyncio


bot = Bot ('Token')

dp = Dispatcher (bot)

@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def command_start(message : types.Message):
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        now = datetime.now()
        current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        if current_time == '11:59:00':
#вариант 1 не сработал.
           await bot.send_message(chat_id={number group}, message_thread_id={topic in group}, text="/all", entities = [aiogram.types.message_entity.MessageEntity(length = 3, offset= 2, type= "mention")])
#Обычный текста в чат работает но не знаю как тригернуть всех по никам(именам пользователей), чтобы в тг было упоминание пользователя через @
            await bot.send_message(chat_id = {number group}, message_thread_id= {topic in group}, text = "Тест сообщения")


Здесь
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63781592/what-should-i-do-if-i-want-tag-all-members-of-a-group-in-telegram-python-bot
уже дан ответ: либо нужно использовать закреп сообщение -- все юзеры получат уведомление об этом (лимитов на это нет), либо упоминать юзеров пачками (в решении по ссылке предлагается по 8 айди за сообщение). В защиту этого решения могу сказать только одно -- те чаты, что я видел постоянно работающими, именно так и делают -- тегают юзеров небольшими порциями (часто набивая рандомные эмодзи вместо сообщения)
